# modified recorded wireshark pcap with bittwiste don't seem working

Tags: wireshark

I have a wireshark recorded pcap file, two machines (m1 and m2) in the same network,

first I used `bittwiste.exe` to alter all packets in that pcap to have different source(`m1_ip`)/destination(`m2_ip`):

```
C:\Windows\System32\bittwiste.exe -I packets.pcap -O packetsModified.pcap -T ip -s 192.168.1.104,m1_ip -d 192.168.1.31,m2_ip
```

Then use `bittwist.exe` to find out the network interface in m1:

```
C:\Users\pete\Documents\tmp>C:\Windows\System32\bittwist.exe -d
```

1. \Device\NPF_{4F9C1634-3817-41FF-96A5-5818BEDA9418} (Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Network Connection)

Then use `bittwist.exe` to send the modified packets to that interface in m1:

```
C:\Users\pete\Documents\tmp>C:\Windows\System32\bittwist.exe -i 1 -m 0.001 packetsModified.pcap
```

In both m1 and m2, I run wireshark to capture traffic (with and without filters to narrow down the relevant packets), but I can only see packets with `src m1_ip`/`dst m2_ip` appear in wireshark of m1, but not m2, I don’t understand why the packets seem don’t arrive from m1 to m2.

If I ping `m2_ip` from m1, I can see reply and ICMP packets appear in both wireshark in m1 and m2. Both firewalls in m1 and m2 are off. 
Anyone has idea?

Answer (score 0):

I can answer it myself now, yes I need to alter both MAC addr and IP addr of the recorded pcap file with bittwiste. after that the recorded pcap can be replayed by tools such as bittwist or tcpreplay